# Getting a particular field from LookUp in MS CRM in c# to fetch value of a particular field

Tags: c#, crm

1. Entity name Person
   2 Person contains a lookup named BirthPlace which is a lookup to another entity
2. Need to get value of a particular field from the lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not conatin complete info, you mentioned what your end result is, but how about when are you firing your plugin (c#) code.

I assume here, you have Entity Person and it's guid available with you.

Now first you retrive Person Entity record with all it's field

```
Entity _personEntity = Service.Retrieve("Person",GuidOfRecord,new ColumnSet(true));
```

Then you get BirthPlace, as it is lookup field it is EntityReference type in c#

```
var _birthPlace=_personEntity.getAttributeValue<EntityReference>("BirthPlace");
```

Then you can get either Id or Name.

```
_birthPlace.Id;
_birthPlace.Name;
```